# Could python have suffix-based number notation for engineering purposes?

Tags: python, numbers, notation

As an electrical engineer I (we?) use python for helping out with calculation/automation/etc.

When dealing with calculations using some real-world numbers it is VERY common to think in **-nano, -pico, -tera**, etc. way.

For example: I know what a 1pF capacitor is, but 1e-12 F capacitor is somewhow less friendly. Also, it is 4x more typing (**1p vs 1e-12**) and more error prone. Not to say that when displaying numbers, having suffixed number is simply easier.

So the question is: is it possible to have this working in python (IPython?):

```
L = 1n
C = 1p
f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(L*C))
print(f) gives: 5.033G (or whatever the accuracy should be)
```

It would be incredibly useful also as just a calculator!

Thanks.

UPDATE:
What I look for is not *units* handling, but just **suffixed numbers** handling. So don't care whether it's a farad or a kilogram, but DO care about the suffix (-n,-u,-m,-M,-G...)

Comment: More generally, it would be great to have a module for Python that could [deal with units as Frink can](http://futureboy.us/frinkdocs/#SampleCalculations) :)

Comment: ... although it seems that there are [quite a few options](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-ideas/2010-March/006899.html)

Comment: Well, maybe the farad made it confusing. I don't look for support of units (or converting between them) but *simply* support for suffixed number parsing. so that 1p is the same as 1e-12

Comment: I know - I was just mentioning them out of interest (or amusement in the case of Frink) - which is why that was just a comment

Answer (score 3):

Sure. Just write your own parser and generate your own AST with [Python's language services](http://docs.python.org/library/language.html).

Comment: @delnan: CPU is cheap, programmers are expensive. "Practical" is relative.

Comment: Uii...! This look powerful, but not being _exactly_ a programmer but an engineer I look for something existing :)

Comment: @Ignacio: I mean impractical as in "someone needs to write that parser, and that someone will need quite a while and experience with parsing".

Comment: Any idea if anybody DID write such parser? It seems like the best idea I got.

Comment: Also I wonder why this could not make it to standard python syntax? there are no variable names starting with a number, so 1n, 150M is quite natural way to express a number... Or is there a wall I do not see?

Answer (score 3):

You could create a module with all the necessary units as symbols, say units.py, containing something like

```
pico = 1*e-12
nano = 1*e-9
micro = 1*e-6
mili = 1*e-3 

Farad = 1

pF = pico*Farad
nF = nano*Farad
```

then in code, 50pF in Farads is

```
units
50*units.pF
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but this does not bring any simplicity does it?

Comment: I guess it depends on your idea of simplicity. To me is seems easier and more scalable than writing a parser.

Comment: yes, but it does not need to be VERY scalable and extensible, as there are only 21 (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_magnitude) values necessary...

Comment: Sure, but you may want to apply the order of magnitude to dimensions other than Farad. This approach deals with magnitude and dimension, however this may be more than what you need.

Comment: Indeed. For managing real 'units' there is plenty of packages, but not for managing _just_ the numbers...

Answer (score 1):

Does not make much sense to introduce complexity in the language for something that can be simply be solved with proper naming and functions:

```
L_nano = unit_nano(1)
C_pico = unit_pico(1)
f = 1/(2*pi*sqrt(L*C))

print(to_Giga(f)) gives: 5.033G
```

Comment: Yes, of course, but what I am looking for is **simplicity** not complexity. This is more complex then just 1p, isn't it?

Comment: Is it? Write the parser code as Ignacio told you and then we can compare

Comment: Indeed, the extra work here is zero and big there, but afterwards the usability difference is HUGE (again, 1p agains 1e-12 against unit_pico(1))

Answer (score 1):

The examples that come with pyparsing include a simple expression parser, called [fourFn.py](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/fourFn.py).  I adapted it to accept your suffixed literals with about 8 lines of additional code, find it [here](http://pastebin.com/mJh6i4Uq). This change supports the [standard suffixes](http://www.simetric.co.uk/siprefix.htm), with the exception of "da" for 1e1, since I was limited to using single characters, I used "D" instead.

If you want to make this into an interactive calculator, you can adapt [Steven Siew's submission](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/file/view/SimpleCalc.py) using the same changes I made to fourFn.py.

Comment: Hm. yes that should work in an application such as a calculator, however, not in "normal" python. Either way thanks, that can actually be useful. I guess the custom parser solution is the closest...